# Javascript Incomplete tags

Tags: javascript

I work for a nascent online retailer in Ghana, West Africa. We purchased an E-commerce template from Big Commerce. On our website there's a text-field where users are allowed to enter their email addresses and receive newsletters subsequently. Unfortunately, when users enter information, its not seen at the back end. They don't receive the automatic email once they hit enter.  i suspect there's something wrong with Javascript code. Please advise:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // 
      $('#subscribe_form').submit(function() {
        if($('#nl_email').val() == '') {
      // alert('You forgot to type in your email address.');
        $('#nl_email').focus();
        return true;
           }

    if($('#nl_email').val().indexOf('@') == -1 || $('#nl_email').val().indexOf('.') == -1) {
              //alert('Please enter a valid email address, such as john@example.com.');
              $('#nl_email').focus();
               $('#nl_email').select();
                return true;
           }

    // Set the action of the form to stop spammers
    $('#subscribe_form').append("<input type="hidden" name="check" value="1" />");
    return true;

     });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error here

```
$('#subscribe_form').append("<input type="hidden" name="check" value="1" />");
```

Fix:

```
$('#subscribe_form').append("<input type='hidde' name='check' value='1' />");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting:

```
$('#subscribe_form').append("<input type="hidden" name="check" value="1" />");
```

as

```
$('#subscribe_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="check" value="1" />');
```

or it will raise an error because of the quotes...